# R gt summary_row but no new column

Tags: r, gt

I am using the GT() Package to make a very simple table.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Size = c("Small", "Medium", "Large"),
  Sold = c(1000, 2000, 3000)
)

df %>%
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_number(
    columns = vars(Sold),
    sep_mark = ",",
    drop_trailing_zeros = T
  ) %>% 
  summary_rows(
    columns = vars(Sold),
    fns = list(
      Total = ~sum(.))
  )
```

However there is a -- column, I want the total to be below the size, but still being a summary row. Because I can change color and size easier.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the missing_text argument with an empty value

```
library(gt)
df <- data.frame(
  Size = c("Small", "Medium", "Large"),
  Sold = c(1000, 2000, 3000)
)

df %>%
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_number(
    columns = vars(Sold),
    sep_mark = ",",
    drop_trailing_zeros = T
  ) %>% 
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = vars(Sold),
    fns = list(
         Total = ~sum(.)), 
         missing_text = ' '
  )
```

[image: ExampleTable]

Comment: Thanks! I ended up switching to hux table buy janitor::adorn_totals also kind of works